# How can I solve this problem textfield get value in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AppStateManager manager = AppStateManager.of(context);

    String textLetter = manager.appState.replacementsController.text;
    String textCodeElec = manager.appState.replacementsController.value.text;
    log('data: ${manager.appState.textEditingDeltaHistory.length}');

    if (textLetter == 'a' || textLetter == 'A') {
      textCodeElec = '90'; //a print 90
    }
    if (textLetter == 'b' || textLetter == 'B') {
      textCodeElec = '88';// b print 88
    }
    if (textLetter == 'ao' || textLetter == 'Ao') {
      textCodeElec = '94';// but bao print bao are not 88 94
    }
    // log('textLetter: ${textLetter}');
    log('textCodeElec: ${textCodeElec}');
    return Column(
      children: [
        _buildTextEditingDeltaViewCode(textCodeElec),
        _buildTextEditingDeltaViewHeader(),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.separated(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35.0),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return _buildTextEditingDeltaHistoryViews(
                  manager.appState.textEditingDeltaHistory)[index];
            },
            itemCount: manager.appState.textEditingDeltaHistory.length,
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const SizedBox(height: 2.0);
            },
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I have tried many ways but it still does not display as requested when b = 88, ao = 94 but 'bao = bao' is not 'bao = 88 94'.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your goal**

When the user types text, it should test if it starts with some key characters (a, b, ao), if this is the case it should add to *textCodeElec* a number, check if the rest of the value is equal to others key character and add them if it is the case.

Ecamples:

- for b it should return 88
- for bao it should return 88 94
- for aao it should return 90 94

**The reason why it doesn't work**

In your conditions, you are using "==" comparator so when you type "bao" it is not equal to "b" or "ao" which is why it returns the same value.

**Solution**

To solve that you can use *startsWith* which will check if the value start with a key character, if it is the case you will the value of that key and then retrieve that key for the text so you can test it with next key values.

```
if (textLetter.toLowerCase().startsWith('a')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 90'; //a print 90
      // remove a from textLetter
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
}
if (textLetter.toLowerCase().startsWith('b')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 88';// b print 88
      // remove b from textLetter
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
}
if (textLetter.toLowerCase().startsWith('ao')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 94';// but bao print bao are not 88 94
      // remove ao from textLetter
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(2);
}

//remove all spaces at the beginning and at the end
textCodeElec = textCodeElec.trim();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand and have solved the problem. I wish you good health

Comment: Sir, I want to print a sentence like "bao bao", then the number I want to display is 88 94 88 94, what should I do?

Comment: Sir, if that value is a space, how should we do it because when it is a space, doing it this way is almost impossible?

Answer (score 0):

`bao` is a different value than `b` and `ao`.
If you want to display `88 94` when value is `bao` then you should add:

```
if (textLetter == 'bao' || textLetter == 'Bao') {
  textCodeElec = '88 94';
}
```

to your code.